# Using Serilog to log generic object

Tags: serilog

Is it possible to log in a method where the incoming argument is generic?  For example

```
public async Task<TResult> Handle(TQuery query)
{
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var result = await _handler.Handle(query);
    watch.Stop();
    Serilog.Log.Logger.Information("Processed {@" + query.GetType().Name + "} in {Elapsed} ms",
        query.GetType().Name, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    return result;
}
```

Note in the above, I'm using string concatenation in the template and I'm not sure this is a best practice.  Is there another way to log the incoming object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you considered just passing the type of the query object through, or the query object itself? E.g.:

```
Log.Information("Processed {@Query} in {Elapsed} ms", query, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

This will print output like:

```
Processed SomeQuery { SomeProp = "foo" } in 100 ms
```

Comment: could it be that simple!?  Would logging it this way allow me to run interesting queries against it as in your blog post here (http://nblumhardt.com/2013/06/serilog-and-ravendb/)?

Comment: took me a little bit longer to verify but very cool.  Thank you very much